# Automatically Find and Set Recommended Resolution in Windows

Tags: batch-file, command-line, window

There is a recommended screen resolution for every PC. Is there any way to automatically set screen resolution to recommended one using command prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monitors have a specific resolution. If set to any other size scaling takes place. There is no command line feature to change resolution.